# How to set active form for all time?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to set a form to be active all the time? No matter if I open another forms, the form which I opened sets inactive and that other sets active.
For example:
I have two forms: "Main Form" and "Reminder Form". When I start the application it loads the "Reminder Form", then the "Main Form" loads and after that "Main Form" is active, but I want, that "Reminder Form" is active, but the sequence of how forms loads needs to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by saying "active" you mean have a focus always, it's not possible in built-in way, it should be handled by you. If you want that it's always visible (it's on top of other forms), you can use `TopMost=true` attribute, so it will be always over all *non TopMost* forms, which, by the way, is not guranteed in case of appearance of another TopMost form.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
public ReminderForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainForm frm2 = new MainForm();
    MainForm.Show();
    Activate();
}
```

If you want your form to stay always on top of other forms, set `TopMost = true;`

Answer (score 0):

You could register to the [`Deactivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate.aspx) event and then call [`Activate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) to make the form active again:

```
public ReminderForm()
{
    //other stuff
    Deactivate += (s, e) => { if (/* check if really do it */) Activate(); };
}
```

If you just want the 'Reminder Form' to be visible, setting [`TopMost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) to true is the easier way.

Answer (score 0):

set the `TopMost` property of the form to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        this.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set `TopMost` property to `True`